How can I optimize the integration between Oracle and GridDB when joining large tables
I’m currently working on integrating GridDB with Oracle 19c for a data-intensive application. The goal is to store some time-series data in GridDB while performing complex ETL processes and queries in Oracle. One of the Oracle tables is partitioned and contains over 500 million records. The query performance is significantly slower than expected, even with indexing and partitioning.
Here’s a simplified version of the query I’m running in Oracle 19c that also pulls data from GridDB via an API:
SELECT t1.customer_name, t2.product_name, SUM(t1.amount), gdb.stock_price FROM transactions t1 JOIN products t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id JOIN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(griddb_stock_price_api())) gdb ON t1.product_id = gdb.product_id WHERE t1.transaction_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('2023-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2023-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') GROUP BY t1.customer_name, t2.product_name, gdb.stock_price;

Data Details:
transactions (Oracle):
customer_name: Name of the customer making the transaction.
product_id: The ID of the product being purchased.
amount: The transaction amount.
transaction_date: The date the transaction was made (partitioned by date).
products (Oracle):Data Details:
transactions (Oracle):
customer_name: Name of the customer making the transaction.
product_id: The ID of the product being purchased.
amount: The transaction amount.
transaction_date: The date the transaction was made (partitioned by date).
products (Oracle):
product_id: The ID of the product.
product_name: The name of the product.
griddb_stock_price_api() (GridDB): This API function retrieves real-time stock price data from GridDB.
product_id: The product ID linked to the stock price.
stock_price: The current stock price for the product.
product_id: The ID of the product.
product_name: The name of the product.
griddb_stock_price_api() (GridDB): This API function retrieves real-time stock price data from GridDB.
product_id: The product ID linked to the stock price.
stock_price: The current stock price for the product.

It works for me. You can try this
Cache Data from GridDB in Oracle:
Instead of fetching data from GridDB in real-time for each query, you can periodically cache the stock price data in an Oracle staging table. This eliminates the overhead of making multiple API calls.
Steps:
Create a table to store the cached stock prices:
CREATE TABLE stock_price_cache AS
SELECT * FROM TABLE(griddb_stock_price_api());

Refresh the cache periodically (daily/hourly) using a scheduled job:
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM stock_price_cache;
  INSERT INTO stock_price_cache SELECT * FROM TABLE(griddb_stock_price_api());
END;

Modify your query to use the cache instead of making real-time API calls.
SELECT t1.customer_name, t2.product_name, SUM(t1.amount), gdb.stock_price
FROM transactions t1
JOIN products t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
JOIN stock_price_cache gdb ON t1.product_id = gdb.product_id
WHERE t1.transaction_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('2023-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2023-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY t1.customer_name, t2.product_name, gdb.stock_price;

Caching GridDB data, using materialized views, and batching API calls will significantly reduce the performance hit caused by external API calls. Combine that with Oracle’s query optimization features like partitioning, parallel processing, and adaptive query plans to ensure the best performance.
